# Unable to load crossroads.js using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, crossroadsjs

I try to load JS files using RequireJS , however crossroads http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/  seems not be loaded properly. I have checked using Chrome Dev Toolbar and all JS files are actually loaded. However running **window.crossroad** returned me **undefined**?

Below is my requirejs config.. Kindly advice... Thanks!

**index.html**

```
<script data-main="scripts/config" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

**config.js**

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    "zepto.min": {
      exports: "$"
    },
    "underscore.min": {
      exports: "_"
    },
    "crossroads.min": {
      exports: "crossroads"
    }  }
});

require(["zepto.min","underscore.min", "crossroads.min",], function() {
    console.log("=> Loading app")
    require(["main"]);
});
```

**main.js**

```
require(["hp-config", "hp-model", "hp-view", "hp-controller"], function () {
    console.log("=> Init");
    console.log(window.crossroads);
    //$(document).ready( function(){ HP.C.init(); });
});
```

Comment: I found that even window.signals is undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for crossroads, you'll see that it detects that it is in a AMD environment (which RequireJS is) and calls `define` by itself. So you should remove the shim you have for it. The basic rule is: a library that does not call `define` needs a shim but a library that calls `define` does not. The reason `window.crossroads` is undefined is that crossroads calls `define` *instead of* exporting itself in the global space (on `window`).

Given the `require.config` call you currently have, the updated call would be:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    "zepto.min": {
      exports: "$"
    },
    "underscore.min": {
      exports: "_"
    }
  }
});
```

The above config is the minimum change required. However, I would also advise *not* using `.min` in the names you pass to `require` or `define`. So your `config.js` could be instead:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    zepto: "zepto.min",
    underscore: "underscore.min",
    crossroads: "crossroads.min"
  },
  shim: {
    zepto: {
      exports: "$"
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    }
  }
});

require(["zepto","underscore", "crossroads",], function() {
    console.log("=> Loading app")
    require(["main"]);
});
```

This way, if you want to switch to the non-minified version (for debugging) you can just change the `paths` setting instead of having to go everywhere you require these modules and change the names.

Comment: thank you Louis, would you mind to share the correct config.js based on your explanation , sorry I am new to requirejs